# Dynamic OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have an Openstreet map which Ive programmed two selection options to narrow down on the map. Everything works beautifully but when in option is selected on one of the drop down menus the map viewpoint changes so the user has to manually click and drag back into the selected points on the 
map. I would like the viewpoint to remain on the state of Oklahoma or where the user last adjusted the zoom or pan.

See
https://www.tcokchallenge.com/admin_cp/openmap/openstreet.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the view using an extent on the view.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({ extent: [...] }) 
});
```

According to [the doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html)

> The extent that constrains the center, in other words, center cannot be set outside this extent.

Comment: I don't know how to implement this into my current application.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you have issues retrieving the extent? Assuming you use a vector source to add your points you could do:

Comment: `layer.getSource().getExtent()` and pass it to the constructor of the `ol.View`. So first create the layer add the points and finally compute the extent.